# Privacy Rights vs Book Covers

Tags: publicity-rights

One can legally write about famous people (and display pictures of them) without their permission, but you can not legally use their name or image in advertising without their permission. So, I could write a book about some politician (e.g. Benjamin Netanyahu) or corporate tycoon (Bill Gates), but if I create a website advertising my book, I could not mention their names or include pictures of them. At least, that appears to be the gist of what I've read on the subject.

What I'm confused about is book covers; do they qualify as advertising as well? Some references warn against putting a person's picture on a book cover, yet I see books featuring their pictures on the cover all the time (e.g. Controligarchs, which features pictures of five famous individuals). (I'm assuming the people profiled in this book didn't give permission to use their pictures on the cover, though I could obviously be wrong.)

So, my question is: can I legally put a picture of a famous person on a book cover without their permission? Or is this a more complex question - maybe there are certain situations where the practice is legal?